# Get sums grouped by date by same column filtered by 2 conditions

Tags: python, pandas

Have dataset like.

```
    TransactionId   UserId transaction_date transaction_status amount_USD
0       3996625673  1298122       2015-08-11            CHARGED      10,96
1       5797849338  1125916       2015-08-11           DECLINED       14,7
2       9535361884  8009005       2015-08-11            CHARGED      10,61
3       8410989235  1123856       2015-07-29           DECLINED      10,96
```

Need to get sum by column amount_usd in case of transaction_date,
transaction_status

```
transaction_date    CHARGED DECLINED
2015-07-29             0     10,96
2015-08-11           21,57   14,7
```

Tried to do in way like

```
df[df['transaction_status']=='DECLINED']['amount_USD'].groupby('transaction_date').sum()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) for numeric first and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregate `sum`, then reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
#or use parameter decimal=',' to read_csv
df['amount_USD'] = df['amount_USD'].replace(',','.', regex=True).astype(float)

df = df.groupby(['transaction_date','transaction_status'])['amount_USD']
       .sum()
       .unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
transaction_status  CHARGED  DECLINED
transaction_date                     
2015-07-29             0.00     10.96
2015-08-11            21.57     14.70
```

Alternative with [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html), thanks [Bharath shetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46847474/filter-column-by-value-and-group-by-date/46847528#comment80642379_46847528):

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='transaction_date',
                    columns='transaction_status', 
                    values='amount_USD', 
                    aggfunc='sum', 
                    fill_value=0)
print (df)

transaction_status  CHARGED  DECLINED
transaction_date                     
2015-07-29             0.00     10.96
2015-08-11            21.57     14.70
```

Last for column from index use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = df.reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
  transaction_date  CHARGED  DECLINED
0       2015-07-29     0.00     10.96
1       2015-08-11    21.57     14.70
```

Comment: You can also use pivot table will you add that

Comment: `df.pivot_table(index=['transaction_date'],columns=['transaction_status'],values='amount_USD',aggfunc='sum').fillna(0)`